# Not Able to fetch element using Get Element in Robot Framework

Tags: robotframework

I have the below xml snippet and i am unable to fetch the element using Get Element.

> 

```
<configuration commit-localtime="2020-06-27 12:48:13 IST" commit-seconds="1593242293" commit-user="root">
    <groups>
        <name>group1</name>
        <interfaces>
            <interface>
                <name>&lt;*&gt;</name>
                <unit>
```

Is the xpath=configuration/groups/name incorrect?
Have also tried xpath=name but does not work.

Get error as    No element matching 'configuration/groups/name' found

Comment: Welcome. Are you using XML library? Is this the whole XML where you're trying to find the element? Can you add your RF code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Xpath is incorrect, I have created a small test case as an example. In it you can see an xpath expression that returns what you want.

```
Fetch element in XML document
    ${root} =       Parse XML       ${XML}      
    log       ${root}
    ${first} =      Get Element     ${root}             xpath=.//groups/name
    Should Be Equal                 ${first.text}       group1
```